# Add posixlt as a new column to a dataframe

Tags: r

I am creating some random numbers:

```
data <- matrix(runif(10, 0, 1), ncol = 2)
dataframe <- data.frame(data)

> dataframe
         X1         X2
1 0.7981783 0.13233858
2 0.9592338 0.05512942
3 0.1812384 0.74571334
4 0.1447498 0.96656930
5 0.1735390 0.37345575
```

and I want to create a corresponding timestamp column and bind that to the above data frame.

```
time <- as.POSIXlt(runif(10, 0, 60), origin = "2017-05-05 10:00:00")
```

This creates 10 values.

```
> time
 [1] "2017-05-05 13:00:27 EEST" "2017-05-05 13:00:02 EEST" "2017-05-05 13:00:26 EEST" "2017-05-05 13:00:25 EEST" "2017-05-05 13:00:28 EEST"
 [6] "2017-05-05 13:00:17 EEST" "2017-05-05 13:00:35 EEST" "2017-05-05 13:00:08 EEST" "2017-05-05 13:00:29 EEST" "2017-05-05 13:00:32 EEST"
```

Now, I want to bind it to the dataframe, so I thought first to make it a matrix:

```
time <- matrix(time, nrow = 5, ncol = 2)
```

but this gives me:

```
Warning message:
In matrix(time, nrow = 5, ncol = 2) :
  data length [11] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [5]
```

Comment: use `as.POSIXct` instead of `lt`

Comment: @akrun:You are right!Thanks!Is there a way to preserve the date time format though?Because converting to matrix shows seconds.

Comment: updated the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `POSIXlt` stores the date time as a `list` of attributes whereas `POSIXct` would not.  So, it is better to use `as.POSIXct`

```
time <- as.POSIXct(runif(10, 0, 60), origin = "2017-05-05 10:00:00")
```

If we need to store, it can be done as a `list` of `data.frame`

```
data.frame(date1= time[1:5], date2 = time[6:10])
```

without converting to `matrix` as 'Datetime' gets coerced to `integer` storage mode when converted to `matrix`.

---

Suppose, we proceed with `POSIXlt`, then we find the `list` of attributes

```
time1 <- as.POSIXlt(runif(10, 0, 60), origin = "2017-05-05 10:00:00")
unclass(time1)
#$sec
# [1] 13.424695 40.860449 57.756890 59.072140 24.425521 39.429729 58.309546
# [8]  6.294982 46.613436 25.444415

#$min
# [1] 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30

#$hour
# [1] 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15

#$mday
# [1] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5

#$mon
# [1] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4

#$year
# [1] 117 117 117 117 117 117 117 117 117 117

#$wday
# [1] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5

#$yday
# [1] 124 124 124 124 124 124 124 124 124 124

#$isdst
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

#$zone
# [1] "IST" "IST" "IST" "IST" "IST" "IST" "IST" "IST" "IST" "IST"

#$gmtoff
# [1] 19800 19800 19800 19800 19800 19800 19800 19800 19800 19800

#attr(,"tzone")
#[1] ""    "IST" "IST"
```

With `POSIXct`, it is the integer storage values that can be found by `unclass`

```
 unclass(time)
 #[1] 1493978445 1493978451 1493978432 1493978402 1493978447 1493978441
 #[7] 1493978445 1493978450 1493978419 1493978425
 #attr(,"tzone")
 #[1] ""
```