# "Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied" When Trying To Add POSIXlt To Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, lubridate, posixlt

I'm looking to write a script that can simply correct dates in a data frame (observations) that have two digit years to have four digits. I have all of the logic, but I get an error when I run this code:

```
observations[1,"Datetime_UTC"] <- observations[1,"Datetime_UTC"] + years(2000)
```

This line results in:

```
# Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

How do I resolve this error?

Thank you!

Comment: That error indicates that the value you are converting to `POSIXlt` is just a number, not a string or existing `POSIXt`-friendly format. Because of that, how to interpret it depends on the source of the data. Many tools use the unix "epoch" (seconds since "1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC"), but many (including Excel) use different origins and units. Try adding `origin="1970-01-01"` (if epoch seconds)

Comment: Also: You should NOT use POSIXlt vectors in data.frames. Use POSIXct instead.

Comment: @IRTFM Why should POSIXlt vectors not be used in data.frames?

Comment: Because POSIXlt vectors are actually lists and dataframe functions do not support accessing dataframe columns that are lists.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43799852/add-posixlt-as-a-new-column-to-a-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dates are stored with some regular formatting, but with 2-digit years, just let `lubridate` functions handle it. They can handle most delimiters (even unusual ones).

```
library(lubridate)
ymd("20/11/9")
"2020-11-09"
dmy("31-1-90")
"1990-01-31"
mdy("3_07_00")
"2000-03-07"
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I had tried those before and they hadn't worked, but I hadn't tried mdy_hms(), which is how my data are formatted.